# complex integration paths

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, complex-integration

I was doing this question and stuck at just simple point
[image]

what is $[.]$ this symbol ?
for homologous and homotopic part i will try to see what these terms are on internet.. butcan you help me **what is i) part**

But I would be obliged if you do all parts or give hints for all parts... but so far i am concerned very much with first part only..
is it greatest integer function or anything else ?

Comment: Homology class or homotopy class, depending.

Comment: Since they're being added, most likely homology class.

Comment: ohh okay thanks .. let me see that